# Create data hierarchy in excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel file, 
where there is a column "Name"
under which There is Total revenue
next row has net premium earned and so on. As far as I saw the data its hierarchy is based on line spacing in each cell.
How can I achieve the data hierarchy as in pivot table? Or how should i\I arrange this data so that I can achieve the structure in pivot.
Data from : https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnys/aig/financials

[image]

Comment: What ***exactly*** are you trying to achieve in a pivot table?

Comment: For example, under Total Revenue I should have     Net Premiums Earned
    Fees and Commission Income
    Net Investment Income, Revenue
    Net Investment Income, Revenue
    Net Investment Income, Revenue
    Net Foreign Exchange Gain/Loss, Revenue
    Other Revenue
    Rental Income, Revenue, under     Net Investment Income, Revenue I should have         Realized Gain/Loss on Investments, Revenue
        Impairment/Reversals of Investments, Revenue
        Gains/Loss on Derivatives, Revenue

Comment: Please, this is unreadable. Edit your question and use words to describe what you want to achieve, like "I want to indent text x by y characters"